# Activity does not get shown

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities.

Main activities send an intent to activityB (a question)
activityB takes the answer as intput and send the answer to activityC
activityC displays the answer

actifityC does not show up and I have a

Here are my files

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ebookfrenzy.explicitintent"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="189dp"
        android:onClick="askQuestion"
        android:text="@string/ask_question"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

main_activity.java

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.explicitintent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int request_code = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void askQuestion(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

        final EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String myString = editText1.getText().toString();
        i.putExtra("qString", myString);
        startActivityForResult(i, request_code);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if ((requestCode == request_code) &&
                (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            String returnString =
                    data.getExtras().getString("returnData");

            textView1.setText(returnString);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityB">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
        android:onClick="sendAnswer"
        android:text="Send Answer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.534"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.349" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="316dp"
        android:onClick="answerQuestion"
        android:text="Answer Question"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.565"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activityB.java

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.explicitintent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int request_code = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }

        String qString = extras.getString("qString");

        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(qString);

    }



//    public void answerQuestion(View view) { finish(); }

    public void sendAnswer(View view) {
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
        EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String returnString = editText1.getText().toString();
        i2.putExtra("returnData", returnString);
        startActivity(i2);
    }

}

activity_c.xml
    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityC">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.528"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="ANSWER"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.528"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activityC.java

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.explicitintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class ActivityC  extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int request_code = 5;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String returnString = extras.getString("returnData");

        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(returnString);

    }

}




buikd is successful

I get an exception in activityB.java 
at the last line in the codde line calling  of  `startActivity(i2)`
```

thos is the exception I get

```
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
```

manifet file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ebookfrenzy.explicitintent">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityB"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where is activity B here in your code?

Comment: activity.java
activity_b.xml

Comment: Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: @TarekEZZAT i added answer

Comment: This is way too much code. In the future you need to reduce the stuff you post to the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1):

you have given a wrong id to textview in activity C
and also mention activity C in your manifest

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String returnString = extras.getString("returnData");

    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.title);//make change here...
    textView.setText(returnString);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not registered Activity C in manifest file.
Add in application tag:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityC"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise editText1 in onCreatee method. May be you sending null value in putExtra.

Send Answer method in Activity B.

Or if problem not solved then please add error log in comment

Comment: No null value sent
I checked with the debugger

Comment: ok please try in activity C->         
String returnString = getIntent().getStringExtra("returnData");

Comment: @Wini provided the solution>
Also thanks to Bilal Aslam too